# How to know if an API service is down or up

Tags: api, rest, django-rest-framework, status

How can I know if an API service (e.g. Garmin health API) is down or not when calling from an application? I want to implement a way in my system so that when any API service is down for maintenance or any other reason, the application from where it's called can take some measures like showing a related message to the users who are calling it.